# Can't set maximum queue length in Rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, py-amqplib

I'm trying to set the max length for a Rabbitmq queue using the Python amqplib library.
But the queue does not get limited.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html

I've reset the Rabbitmq server each time to delete the queue.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
args = {"x-max-length":2}
    self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self.queue_name, durable=durable,
        exclusive=exclusive, auto_delete=auto_delete, arguments=args)
```

Comment: x-max-length was added in Rabbitmq version 3.1.0. Are you running an older version?